# What is the Platform Toolset name of LLVM installed by Visual Studio Installer in VS 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to call "Clang compiler for Windows" installed by Visual Studio Installer from cmake command line.  According to the platform toolset of an opned `.sln` file, this shall be `clang-cl`, but neither setting the `-T` flag of cmake to `clang-cl` nor `LLVM` works.

[image]

Comment: You should use `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl` rather than `-T clang-cl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the Platform Toolset name of LLVM installed by Visual Studio
>   Installer in VS 2019?

For your situation, you cannot use "-T" to call the `clang-cl` and it is not in the supported toolset. You can use `DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` directly.

> -T  Toolset specification for the generator, if supported.
>
> Some CMake generators support a toolset specification to tell the
>   native build system how to choose a compiler. See the
>   CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET variable for details.

**Solution**

Please try this:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -p "CMakeLists.txt"
```

More info you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285259/configure-cmake-in-windows-to-use-clang-from-command-line-to-get-modern-openmp-s).

**Update 1**

It can be realized by `-T` and use `clangcl` instead of `clang-cl`. In toolset, LLVM is called `clangcl`.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T clangcl
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Just a side note here: Indeed it is possible to use -T flag, but instead of ```clang-cl```, Visual Studio uses ```clangcl```.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. And l have added it in my answer. Thanks a lot.