# OpenMP linking errors in Visual Studio 2019 LLVM

Tags: visual-studio, clang, openmp, llvm, linker-errors

I've been trying to build an **OpenMP** sample program with an LLVM compiler integrated to Visual Studio 2019.

LLVM compiler was downloaded from [here](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html) (version 10.0, win64), *C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin* added to the PATH environment variable. **LLVM Compiler Toolchain** extension was installed from [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarekAniola.mangh-llvm2019).

It successfully builds a hello world program, but when I try to use OpenMP the linker fails with the following errors:

```
1>clang version 10.0.0
1>Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
1>Thread model: posix
1>InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
1> (in-process)
1> "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang-cl.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.26.28805 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name llvmtest.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=none -relaxed-aliasing -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -mllvm -x86-asm-syntax=intel -D_DEBUG -D_MT -D_DLL --dependent-lib=msvcrtd --dependent-lib=oldnames -stack-protector 2 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fexternc-nounwind -fms-volatile -fdefault-calling-conv=cdecl -fdiagnostics-format msvc -gcodeview -debug-info-kind=limited -v -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\10.0.0" -D _DEBUG -D _CONSOLE -D _UNICODE -D UNICODE -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\10.0.0\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\atlmfc\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Auxiliary\\VS\\include" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\ucrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\um" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\shared" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\winrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.18362.0\\cppwinrt" -internal-isystem "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\NETFXSDK\\4.6.1\\Include\\um" -O0 -Wall -Wno-error -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "Z:\\llvmtest" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -fopenmp -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compatibility-version=19.26.28805 -std=c++14 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fno-caret-diagnostics -fdiagnostics-show-option -faddrsig -o "Debug\\llvmtest.obj" -x c++ llvmtest.cpp
1>clang -cc1 version 10.0.0 based upon LLVM 10.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
1>#include "..." search starts here:
1>#include <...> search starts here:
1> C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\10.0.0\include
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\atlmfc\include
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\Include\um
1>End of search list.
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __kmpc_global_thread_num
1>>>> referenced by Z:\llvmtest\llvmtest.cpp:9
1>>>>               Debug\llvmtest.obj:(main)
1>
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __kmpc_push_num_threads
1>>>> referenced by Z:\llvmtest\llvmtest.cpp:15
1>>>>               Debug\llvmtest.obj:(main)
1>
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: __kmpc_fork_call
1>>>> referenced by Z:\llvmtest\llvmtest.cpp:15
1>>>>               Debug\llvmtest.obj:(main)
1>
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: omp_get_thread_num
1>>>> referenced by Z:\llvmtest\llvmtest.cpp:19
1>>>>               Debug\llvmtest.obj:(.omp_outlined._debug__)
1>
1>lld-link : error : undefined symbol: omp_get_num_threads
1>>>> referenced by Z:\llvmtest\llvmtest.cpp:25
1>>>>               Debug\llvmtest.obj:(.omp_outlined._debug__)
1>Done building project "llvmtest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

The code is rather trivial:

```cpp
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int nthreads, tid;

        //omp_set_num_threads(4);   

    #pragma omp parallel private(tid) num_threads(3)
        {               
            tid = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", tid);

            if (tid == 0)
            {
                nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
            }

        }  /* All threads join master thread and terminate */
    }
```

Project settings shown below:
[image]
[image]

I have tried different options: `-fopenmp`, `-Xclang -fopenmp` compiler flags, passing `-openmp` and `-fopenmp` as linker flags, changing x64 to x86, adding *C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib* to the PATH. Nothing helped so far.

Interestingly enough, I can build the same code from the command line by running the following from **x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019**:

```
clang-cl -openmp llvmtest.cpp
```

So, basically, `-openmp` flag was enough... Does anyone have an idea how to make it work in Visual Studio?

Comment: These are all missing symbols from the OpenMP runtime library. Somewhere in the LLVM's `lib` directory there should be a `libomp.lib` file. You need to add it to the additional libraries in the linker settings. The problem is that VS does a separate link step and the linker doesn't know that you need the OpenMP runtime too. When you compile with `clang-cl -openmp ...`, the compiler driver automatically adds the OpenMP runtime library when calling the linker.

Comment: @HristoIliev I was thinking of that, but I don't know how to properly add those libs to the linker. It seems to me 'usual' VS linker settings are irrelevant in this case as I am using LLVM, hence lld-link is used instead of the Microsoft linker. There is 'Additional Linker Options' field under LLVM (see the image), but I have no idea what to pass there. Can you give me a hint on that?

Comment: I guess `-lomp`.

Comment: @HristoIliev lld-link : warning : ignoring unknown argument '-lomp'

Comment: Assuming `lld-link` is command-line compatible with `link`, then the additional option should be `libomp.lib`. You may also need to add the path to LLVM's `lib` directory somewhere too.

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I have managed to make it work (thanks to Marek Aniola, the author of the LLVM Toolchain extension, who helped me out).

First, I passed the `/openmp` flag to **LLVM** -> **Additional Compiler Options** (it works with `-openmp` too).

Second, it turns out that OpenMP is not automatically linked when building from Visual Studio (in contrast to compiling from the command line by means of clang-cl). Linker settings for LLVM are specified the same way as for the Microsoft linker.

The path to libraries *C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib* has to be added to **Linker** -> **General** -> **Additional Library Directories**.

It is also necessary to list *libomp.lib* in **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies**.

**Linker** -> **Optimization** -> **Link Time Code Generation** must be set to **Default**.

These steps let me successfully build the code (64-bit application). Although the 64-bit LLVM compiler can build a 32-bit program, it includes only x64 version of OpenMP libraries, so in order to build a 32-bit application I had to link *libomp.lib* and copy *libomp.dll* from another LLVM distribution. If there is a better way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 16.6.0 comes Clang 10.0.0 that targets both x86 and x64. You can install it using the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, I've tried it first. But it seems to work in CMake projects only. And it also has some issues with finding OpenMP. I think it's discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209524/using-openmp-with-clang-and-cmake-in-visual-studio

Comment: @mentalmushroom, it works if you switch off the error on multi-threading in `Microsoft.Cpp.ClangCl.Common.targets` like this `<!--    <VCMessage Code="MSB8055" Type="Error" Condition="('%(ClCompile.OpenMPSupport)' == 'true')"  /> -->`.

Comment: BTW: Which OpenMP version is supported by Clang in VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mentalmushroom answer, it seems only step two is now necessary:

*"...It is also necessary to list libomp.lib in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies..."*

Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 using LLVM tool-set.

Answer (score 0):

I also spent some time on getting Clang + OpenMP working in Visual Studio 2019. Here's my approach, hopefully it's useful to someone. It largely mimics the approach you would take on Linux with gcc.

Right-click Project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer > Properties:
(1) General > Platform Toolset > LLVM (clang-cl)
(2) C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib\clang\10.0.0\include  *//Tells compiler where to find omp.h (in gcc: -I)*
*//The 64-bit version is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\lib\clang\10.0.0\include*
(3) C/C++ > Command Line > Additional Options > -openmp  //Tells the compiler to use OpenMP (gcc: -fopenmp)
(4) Linker > General > Additional Library Directories > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib  *//Tells linker where to look for the OpenMP library (in gcc: -L)*
*//The 64-bit .lib file is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\lib*
(5) Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > libomp.lib (or whatever the library file is called in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\lib)  *//Tells linker which library to link to (N.B. libomp.lib depends on libomp.dll) (in gcc: -l)*
(6) Add to PATH system environment variable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin  *//Here libomp.dll is located, so Windows can dynamically link the built executable to libomp.dll (in Linux: LD_LIBRARY_PATH)*
*//The 64-bit .dll file is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin*
*//Restart CommandPrompt/PowerShell or computer to reload the environment variables*
(7) Additionally, for 64 bit ([fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563756/fatal-error-lnk1112-module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-typ)):
(7.1) Linker > Target Machine > MachineX64 (/MACHINE:x64)
(7.2) VC++ Directories > Executable Directories > C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin

The above process needs to be repeated for each combination of Release/Debug and x86(or Win32)/x64 (why do people prefer GUIs in a build system...)